# Wordpress Multisite Theme Issue: "Network enabled themes are not shown on this screen."

Tags: wordpress, networking, themes, screen, multisite

I had set up a multisite WordPress. I had installed a theme for the parent site, but it appears "Network enabled themes are not shown on this screen." on the other child site.

Anyone, please help me, thanks

[image1 - All theme had enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcXuO.png)
[image2 - I can't see any theme in child site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEUb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Network enabled themes are themes enabled or disabled by the network admin  at the page **My Sites | Network Admin | Themes**.

To be able to **enable a few of those themes for a specific site only**, you first off have to **disable those very themes networkwide** at that above page.

After disabling those networkwide, you then go to the page **My Sites | Network Admin | Sites**.
Here you choose the URL of the site you want to enable those specific themes for and click the **Edit** link.

Click the tab **Themes** and enable the specific themes for the chosen site there.

Comment: I did this but still theme doesn't apply. By the way, what's the purpose of the network Network Admin Themes then!?